# save data from one sheet to last row of other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Edited to add code to the bottom.

I'm creating an invoice sheet that an employee will populate and then click a "save & clear" button which will find the next empty row in a sales report and save certain fields from the invoice to the sales report. I have two solutions that work but both seem to bog down the sheet take a while to complete. Below is a copy of the sheet I'm working on that I've stripped out extraneous information. Because I've stripped it to bare bones, I don't have an issue with slowness.

I initially tried to create an array of each of the cells I wanted to save and then put those to the report. I then copy and paste values on the report to keep my clear function from deleting the invoice and the report.

Second I have code that is activating certain cells in the lastRow+1 and then I do a copy/paste values of each cell as I go.

Neither feels like the most efficient way to do this but I can't figure out how to use the `getValues` and `setValues` functions. Or if those would be applicable to what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

First Try (with edits):

```
data = ["=Invoice!$E$3", "=Invoice!$E$2","=row()+100000-2","=Invoice!$E$30","=Invoice!$E$4","=Invoice!$C$6","=Invoice!$C$10","=Invoice!$E$6","=Invoice!$E$10","Parts","=Invoice!$H$11"]
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sales Report").appendRow(data);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sales Report");
sheet.getRange('$A$47:$K$100').copyTo(sheet.getRange('$A$47:$K$100'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Invoice').getRange(6,3 ).clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B12:C28').clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E29').clearContent();
```

Second try (with edits):

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sales Report');
var row = spreadsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('A' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('B' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('C' + (row - 1) + 1).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('C' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('D' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('E' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!C6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('F' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!C10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('G' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('H' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!E10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('I' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('J' + (row - 1)).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('J' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('Invoice!H11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('K' + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Invoice').getRange(6,3 ).clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B12:C28').clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E29').clearContent();
```

Comment: I don't see any code here in your post - your post should contain - in the text - the MCVE required to reproduce your issue. Linked documents - especially live ones - are discouraged, because they are not useful to future visitors (i.e. you probably changed the code). I also recommend you use the Apps Script API reference to understand specific methods and classes. It also has a fair number of guides and best practices - all with examples. From the Script Editor: *Help* -> *API reference*

Comment: As with most recorded macros - be it Excel or Google Sheets - you can almost massively improve the macro by removing the crutch where it activates a range, then uses the active range.

Comment: That makes sense. I made some updates to both options trying to eliminate the extra calls to activate a range. I'll post updated code in the original post. I've been using the API reference with (obvious) limited success.

Comment: Feel free to keep only relevant code in the question. A large question is often ignored because it appears to include unnecessary detail, which typically reflects situations where OP simply copy/pasted code and didn't investigate their issue before asking a question. As a further step, have your profiled how long these operations take? I would expect the first method to be decently speedy, albeit I'm not sure how you arrived at some of the values you use.

Comment: I’ll go back and remove some of the code that is old now. Each method is taking about 15-20 seconds. Which doesn’t seem like a long time but feels like forever when you are waiting for it to complete. The clear portion of the code is super zippy now so it has to be coming from the other portions. The Invoice sheet values are coming from certain cells that I need to save on the invoice once the invoice is fully populated. The sales report sheet values are a little random. I need to paste the values and not the formulas since I’m then clearing the invoice. I tried finding the last row but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started with batch value operations (and some concepts).
The key to remember is that JavaScript arrays are 0-base and the Spreadsheet interface uses 1-base: cell A1 aka cell R1C1 is at array indices 0, 0.
The [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) offered by Apps Script's `SpreadsheetApp` also interprets the "major dimension" as rows, so the first index of a "2D" JavaScript `Array` is the row, and the second index is the column of that particular row. (The Sheets REST API can specify that arrays should be interpreted with columns as the first index.)

```
function logInvoice() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // 'const' means we will not change what 'wb' means.
  const sales = wb.getSheetByName("Sales Reports");
  var lastSalesRow = sales.getLastRow(); // not 'const' since we will re-assign this primitive.

  const invoice = wb.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  const fullReport = invoice.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets A1:___ into a 2D JS array
  const data = [
    fullReport[2][4], // E3
    fullReport[1][4], // E2
    /** I really don't know what you were doing with "=row() + 100000 - 2". If
     * you were just trying to get a unique identifier, then use the next line: */
    // Utilities.getUuid(),
    fullReport[29][4], // E30
    /**
     * add more elements as needed
     */
  ];

  // Write the summary data to the next row in the 'Sales Reports' sheet.
  // Grabs the cell "A#" and then uses the size of the data to write to determine
  // the size of the Range required.
  sales.getRange(++lastSalesRow, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  // Reset the Invoice sheet to its blank slate.
  invoice.getRangeList([
    "C6", // R6C3
    "B12:C28",
    "E29"
  ]).clearContent();
}
```

References:

- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [`Sheet#getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [`Range#getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [`Range#setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)